# SetBeforeSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore) not working when inserting parent with child entity with automatic linking with PK ID's = -1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-4.8

I'm migrating a system from Linq-to-sql to Entity Framework Core 3.1 and running into an issue when inserting an new entity which contains another child new entity when both ID (int Identity Specification PK) are set to -1 even after setting the `BeforeSaveBehavior` to Ignore. Our system defaults ID's to -1 so we want to always ignore this on Insert. This works well when inserting single entities but not when inserting entities which relate to other entities.

When I comment out Id = -1 for my new Company entity and leave the Id = -1 for the child Employee entity it works but this would be problematic because setting new entity id's to -1 is widespread through our current solution.

Code
Code below can be found in GitHub: https://github.com/adolfo1981/EFCoreAddNestedIssue

This is a simplified version of the code to reproduce the problem:

**Company Entity:**

```
public partial class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

**Employee Entity:**

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

**Company Configuration:**

```
public partial class CompanyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Company> entity)
    {
        entity.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        
        entity.Property(p => p.Id)
            .UseIdentityColumn();

        entity.Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .Metadata.SetBeforeSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);

        entity.Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150);

        OnConfigurePartial(entity);
    }

    partial void OnConfigurePartial(EntityTypeBuilder<Company> entity);
}
```

**Employee Configuration:**

```
public partial class EmployeeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Employee> entity)
    {
        entity.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        entity.Property(p => p.Id)
            .UseIdentityColumn();

        entity.Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .Metadata.SetBeforeSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);

        entity.Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(200);

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Company)
            .WithMany(p => p.Employees)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Employee_Company");

        OnConfigurePartial(entity);
    }

    partial void OnConfigurePartial(EntityTypeBuilder<Employee> entity);
}
```

**Sample program:**

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AddCompanyWithEmployeeTest();
    }

    private static void AddCompanyWithEmployeeTest()
    {
        using (var context = new EFCoreTestContext())
        {
            var company = new Company
            {
                Id = -1, //Our presentation layer sets Id to -1 for new entities
                Name = "Tesla",
                Employees = new List<Employee> {
                    new Employee {
                        Id = -1, //Our presentation layer sets Id to -1 for new entities
                        Name = "Bob Ross" }
                }
            };

            context.Company.Add(company);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Employee_Company". The conflict occurred in database "EFCoreTest", table "dbo.Company", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

**StackTrace:**

```
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
```

**Provider and version information**

- EF Core version: 3.1.25
- Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer v 3.1.25
- Target framework: .Net Framework 4.8
- Operating system: Windows 11 Pro
- IDE: Visual Studio 2022 17.1.4

Comment: Why do you not set the IDs to `0` before saving?

Comment: That's what I'll most likely do but was hoping to find a solution that would require no changes